# Should paying an NPC to resurrect a Zealot Barbarian be less costly?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian, spell-components, dnd-adventurers-league, resurrection

Zealot Barbarians (from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*) can be the target of resurrection-type spells without the caster being required to spend material components.

In Adventurers League (and probably in non-AL games as well), it is possible to pay for an NPC to resurrect a dead player character (ex: 1250gp for Raise Dead).

Considering that there is no direct mention of it in the existing rules, should the resurrection cost be lowered when the dead player character is a Zealot Barbarian (considering that, logically, part of the price serves as payment for the costly material components)?

(I suppose that if the answer is "yes", a DM may reduce the price by the exact material components cost for the spell in question. Ex: Raise Dead asks for 500gp worth of material components, so the price could be lowered to 750gp instead)

Comment: Are you looking for a Adventurer's League compliant answer? The question is a little ambiguous.

Comment: I'd say the question mostly relates to AL, because i don't know how spellcasting services are handled outside of its scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Logically speaking, yes.

Spellcasters are ultimately running a business, and any business that charges for unnecessary things is liable to find itself out of business in very short order. You still have to pay lifestyle costs, like any other downtime activity, and the GM has final say on whether or not the spell is lowered in price. As you correctly pointed out, a fair portion of the cost of getting spells cast is in obtaining/replacing costly spell reagents.

Comment: though convincing the NPC that the casting will work with out the components may be another task all together.  As they may not have any way to validate that until after the spell is cast.

Comment: While this position makes perfect sense in one's "home" campaign, I think it lacks for discussion of AL's rules regarding spellcasting services, treasure, rewards that last longer than a session, &c. There do exist revised AL guidelines for the incorporation of XGtE material--what do they say about Zealots?

Comment: I'd have them barter with the Resurrector and give them a very very strong advantage