# How much does it cost to cast Raise Dead on a Zealot Barbarian in Adventure's League?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, barbarian, spell-components, resurrection

Based off of the question, [How much should NPCs charge for spells cast as services to PCs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109343/how-much-should-npcs-charge-for-spells-cast-as-services-to-pcs), the cost of spells from NPCs follows the formula:

> Spell Service Cost = Square of the spell level, then multiplied by 10,
>   add double of the consumed material cost, add 10% of nonconsumed
>   material cost.

### Keep in mind, this formula is not official.

The formula was made by the player base, and while official spells have exact costs in certain modules, and the formula itself has no contradictions with the official costs of all known cost of spells, it is not an officially stated formula from DnD 5e material.

With this formula, a level 5 spell would cost 250gp.  Raise Dead, due to the fact that it has a 500gp consumable material, would cost an additional 1000gp.

This is also backed in the same question as the official cost of Raise Dead in Adventure League games, of 1250gp.

However, based off of another question, [Should paying an NPC to resurrect a Zealot Barbarian be less costly?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112798/should-paying-an-npc-to-resurrect-a-zealot-barbarian-be-less-costly), there was no implication that Zealot Barbarians should cost the additional 1000gp due to the fact that they do not require material components to be resurrected.

However, I'm not interested in "shoulds", as it's something you don't want to make an assumption of by the time it becomes relevant.  What would it cost for Raise Dead to be cast on a Zealot Barbarian?  Even if it is the standard rate of 1250gp, I'm interested to know.

Comment: It is important to note that that formula is not official and was only deduced by backcalculating a few spells whose prices were given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## As of current rulings, a Zealot Barbarian must pay the full 1250gp

In the searching I have done, I cannot find any reference to Zealot Barbarians in any Adventurer's League documents, and the rules about spell services make no mention of splitting material costs from the service charges of the caster.

### However...

Adventurer's League documents do specify that spellcasting costs can be changed by the Acolyte background:

> A character possessing the acolyte background requesting spellcasting services at a temple of their faith can request one spell per day from the Spellcasting Services table for free. The only cost paid for the spell is the base price for the **consumed material component**, if any is required.
>
> [AL DMG pg. 6](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/AL_DMG_YP.pdf)

As the Zealot Barbarian would consume no materials to be resurrected, A Zealot Barbarian that is an Acolyte or is partied with an Acolyte of that temple's faith would be able to receive a free Resurrection once per day.

Notably, this background benefit is not applicable to Resurrection or True Resurrection.

Comment: Acolyte Barbarian?  That's what up.  Thanks for the answer, Sirnnamon!  My only issue depends on how pedantic the DM is.  Since you can't really ask to be resurrected if you're dead, they might make that enough of an issue to not resurrect you for free.

Comment: Would it work for the acolyte barbarian?  Technically, if they need the spell, it's going to be hard for them to request it for themselves.  Acolyte party member is obviously legit.

Comment: That comes down to a DM being pretty pedantic in my opinion. I think most dead adventurers have an implicit request to be resurrected. But you could always carry a little note that says "If found please resurrect me" and that might cover you!

Comment: @SirCinnamon Or a tattoo saying the same thing.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Now that would be very in character for a Zealot Barbarian! Hopefully your corpse is intact enough to read it

Comment: A character who was raised as part of the church (a.k.a. "has the Acolyte Background") and who's god "inspires [them] to pitch themselves into a ferocious battle fury" (from the Zealot subclass description) is not likely to need to "request" it. Such a character is chosen by the gods - any rational DM should realize that very same god is likely to *send* people to find and restore one of that god's chosen warriors. Plus... In Adventurers League context, it's always assumed that somebody does recover the remains, assuming there are any remains to be recovered.